# Cannot start fragment from TabLayout

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I have a TabLayout with 2 section.I want to start third single fragment from fragment1.But it's not start the fragment.Just empty view appear in tabview when I click the button.

Simply I want to exit Tabloyout view and start fragment3 when user has click the button.How can I do this ?

Main

```
public class AnaEkran extends AppCompatActivity {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tabdene);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);

        mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(mViewPager));

        /*FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });*/

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_tabdene, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    BlankFragment tab1 = new BlankFragment();
                    return tab1;
                case 1:
                    BlankFragment2 tab2 = new BlankFragment2();
                    return tab2;
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position){
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "FREE";
                case 1:
                    return "PAID";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Main XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".AnaEkran">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:title="OPEN SIGNALS">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tabItem"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tab_text_1" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tabItem2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tab_text_2" />



        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />






</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

TAB 1 Fragment

```
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{





    public BlankFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View myview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);

        ((Button) myview.findViewById(R.id.kredialbeles)).setOnClickListener(this);







        return myview;
    }



    public void onClick(View view) {
        BlankFragment3 fragment3 = new BlankFragment3();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =        fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment3);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }



}
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".BlankFragment">




    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/ScrollView02"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/arkaplan"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp">


        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:fbutton="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/ustarafbeles"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent">



                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/ustbutonlinerbeles"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/kredialbeles"
                        android:layout_width="140dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="20dp"
                        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
                        android:text="@string/buycredit"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                </LinearLayout>




            </RelativeLayout>



        </RelativeLayout>


    </ScrollView>























</FrameLayout>
```

Fragment 3 XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/arkaplan"
    tools:context=".BlankFragment3">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="KEK"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="30dp"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>



</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Create a mainContainer in xml and pass id of that view while opening the third fragment in fragment transaction, put tablayout and viewpager inside that mainContainer as child.

Comment: Please share your layout files.

Comment: I updated first message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I wrap the ViewPager with a layout.

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/llpager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">                     
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />    
</LinearLayout>
```

Then in the TAB1 Fragment inside onclick

```
LinearLayout l = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.llpager);
                    l.removeAllViews();
                    BlankFragment3 fragment3 = new BlankFragment3();
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.llpager, fragment3);
                    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

This will show the Fragment 3 as you expected. I tried to do without l.removeAllViews() but it did not work. Right now I could not check what will happen if I back press. The first thing off course to do is to add back the views in the layout.

Comment: Thank you.But I think use fragment inside activity better than.I create new tablayout and remove the tabs.Only one frragment show inside tab activity.Than I simply use Intent mypage= new Intent(getActivity(), buynow.class);
                startActivity(mypage);